# Prevent Values to change automatically

Tags: excel

I have a csv file that I am opening in excel. The large values are automatically changing in exponential values. eg

```
11  20140729170918  3568990563101700
11  20140729194914  3568990563101700
11  20140729220904  3568990563101700
```

changes to

```
11  2.01407E+13 3.56899E+15
11  2.01407E+13 3.56899E+15
11  2.01407E+13 3.56899E+15
```

I do not want these values to get changed. I can change them using 'format cell' option, but I want to do this automatically and always.

Answer (score 0):

If you import forcing in the dialog the column like Text, import in the correct way.

[image]

If you use VBA:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="E:\0\00.TXT", Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1 _
    , DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
    , Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array _
    (3, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```